# pkcs7-sign in golang not same with .net

Tags: go, pkcs#7

I have a .pfx, need sign data in pkcs7&sha256 in golang, I now have a demo in c#, code is below

```cs
public String SignMsg(string dicMsg，X509Certificate2 certificate) {
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(dicMsg);
   ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
   SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, true);
   CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);
   signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
   signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, false);
   return Convert.ToBase64String (signedCms.Encode ());
}
```

I do something in golang, import https://github.com/mozilla-services/pkcs7,then code is below

```
// getSign 获取签名
func getSign(privateKey *rsa.PrivateKey, cert *x509.Certificate, data []byte) (sign string, err error) {

    signedData, errSign := pkcs7.NewSignedData(data)
    if errSign != nil {
        err = errSign
        return
    }
    signedData.SetDigestAlgorithm(pkcs7.OIDDigestAlgorithmSHA256)

    err = signedData.AddSigner(cert, privateKey, pkcs7.SignerInfoConfig{})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

        signedData.RemoveAuthenticatedAttributes()
    signedData.Detach()
    signRst, errData := signedData.Finish()
    if errData != nil {
        err = errData
        return
    }

    sign = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(signRst)

    return
}
```

my .pfx blocks  has one private key and 3 certs , I use the first cert to do the sign job, and I remove  now the result is different from the .net code run result, some one can tell me why or should i do what to solve the problem, this cost me one whole day

this things i have try

1. import https://github.com/mozilla-services/pkcs7
2. SetDigestAlgorithm(pkcs7.OIDDigestAlgorithmSHA256)
3. signedData.RemoveAuthenticatedAttributes() or not set
4. signedData.Detach()

Comment: i do this to parse cert
1. blocks, errPem := pkcs12.ToPEM(b, keyPassword)
2. loop blocks, get first cert